# iframe canvas having no sound in Safari desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe in my website. That iframe is directing to a game hosted on another website. Everything's going well on all browsers of mobile including safari in iPhones but when it comes to safari on desktop, game is having no sound. This issue only persisting on Desktop safari. There's a "Play" button at the beginning of the game, game and sounds only start after pressing that button. So I'm interacting with the website even before any sounds start, but still no sound.
Here's my code :
[jsfidde](https://jsfiddle.net/maheshkasindi/t895ywv1/)

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; 
overflow: hidden">
<iframe 
src="https://terningspil.dk/spilfiler/backgammon" 
style="position: relative">
</iframe></div>
```